# to be or to become

Tags: phrase-choice

These are images from Onizuka manga.
I don't know what is the difference between "going to be" and "going to become". I would appreciate it someone can tell me which one is the right phrasing and why. Hoping to get an answer, Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Both BE and BECOME are used as main verbs. BE can sometimes work like BECOME as in your example.

> Henceforth I want to be a good student.
>
> Henceforth I want to become a good student.

> She will be a mother soon.
>
> She will become a mother soon.

At the same time, we cannot use these two always interchangeably. Let's see the examples:

> I will be a teacher.

(It can have a meaning "I will become...", with a slightly altered meaning), but I am a teacher doesn't mean I become a teacher.
Similarly, I was a teacher doesn't mean I became a teacher.

> I am a student. # I become a student.
>
> I was a student. # I became a student.

BUT

> I will be a student = / # I will become a student.

BE refers to "remain in a future situation."

> They will be happy.
>
> They will become happy - has a different meaning.

Used as auxiliary verbs (BE = is/am/are/was/were)

> He will be sleeping; don't disturb.
>
> The doctor should be coming any time; please wait.

Here, these are helping verbs, which cannot be the same as BECOME.

Answer (score 0):

"I will be a great teacher" is describing a future state. "I will become a great teacher" is describing a change to that state. In practice, for this example, there is no difference in meaning.

However, "I will be a great teacher at this school" says I will do a great job teaching there and "I will become a great teacher at this school" says that by the time I leave I will be doing a great job teaching, even if I won't be so great when I start. For this similar pair of sentences there is a clear difference in meaning.